# Markov chain in R not leaving initial state

Tags: r, markov-chains

My Markov chain simulation will not leave the initial state 1.  The 4x4 transition matrix has absorption states 0 and 3.

The same code is working for a 3x3 transition matrix without absorption states. What is wrong?

A plot from my code: [Plot of Markov chain simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07A6D.png). And hopefully a working example:

```
# Building Markov transition matrix)
Pc <- matrix(c(1, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0.85, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.65, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 1), 
            nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
rownames(Pc) <- c(0,1,2,3)
colnames(Pc) <- c(0,1,2,3)

#Simulating Markov chain 
markovSimulation <- function(matrix, length, initialState) {
    chain <- array(0,c(length,1))
    chain[1] <- initialState
    for (j in 2:length){
        chain[j] <- sample(1:4, size = 1, prob=matrix[chain[length(chain)] + 1, ])
    }#for loop
    return(chain)
}#markovSimulation

# Calling simulator and plotting result
simulatedChain <- markovSimulation(Pc, 10, 1)
plot(simulatedChain)
```

Comment: This is completely expected if you start a simulation in an absorbing state.

Comment: I think I understand that I did just that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO! Good effort, but I see you got two things wrong:

```
chain[j] <- sample(1:4, size = 1, prob=matrix[chain[length(chain)] + 1, ])
```

you need to sample from `c(0,1,2,3)` as you index your states from 0. and the probabilities need to depend on the previous state, so `prob=matrix[chain[j-1]+1]`.

Then I'm getting reasonable results like this:

```
    > markovSimulation(Pc,10,1)
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    1
 [3,]    2
 [4,]    3
 [5,]    3
 [6,]    3
 [7,]    3
 [8,]    3
 [9,]    3
[10,]    3
```

+1 for nice first post, good reproducible example!

Comment: thanks for the solution and kind words. I had a considerable cactus in my stomach prior to posting. I sincerely wish to present questions that deserve an answer :)

Comment: regarding the indexing: I guess the combination of R indexing starting on 1 and state starting at 0 easily maxes out my reptilian working memory. I'm still puzzled by the `matrix[chain[j - 1] + 1]`

Comment: Hehe, don't worry, you're on a great track. Hope it works well now!

Comment: Yh I would suggest to initially index states 1:4 unless you have a reason not to...that line just picks the row in the matrix that corresponds to the current state - chain[j-1] and since your indexing of states starts from 0, you need to add 1 to align it with indexing of the matrix rows

Comment: I get your point about choosing index states, but in this case I had to make states 0:3. Also understanding starts seeping in on that indexing mechanism. Thanks Jan!

Answer (score 1):

I saw the confusion as due to the fact that you created character indices for your transition matrix and then didn't use them as intended. Using `1` as an i-index would give the first row. Using "1" would give the second row. This uses a character vector of states and uses the character value as a row index into your Pc matrix. Better is to use tmat inside the function rather than a name `matrix` since that is also a function name:

```
markovSimulation <- function(tmat, length, initialState) {
     chain <- array(0,c(length,1))
     chain[1] <- initialState
     for (j in 2:length){
         chain[j] <- sample(0:3, size = 1, prob=tmat[ chain[j-1], ] )
     }#for loop
     return(chain)
 }#markovSimulation

 # Calling simulator and plotting result
 simulatedChain <- markovSimulation(Pc, 100, "1")
 plot(simulatedChain)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried running your code modifications, but could not make them work. I'm sure that is due to my lack of understanding. I agree upon state names as a source of confusion, and I will stop naming matrices as matrix :)

Comment: I just checked the code. It's working fine. Indexing by character values for marginals in matrices is an an expressive feature of the the R language.